# jQuery Hide/Show Divs from Left to Right

Tags: jquery

So I have been searching for a simple jQuery solution to toggleling a sliding action for a div tag from the left to right.

Here is what I have working which slides up/down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
    $x(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
      $x('#slickbox').hide();

    $x.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) { 
       return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback); 
    }; 
    $x("#slick-toggle").click(function () { 
                    $x("#slickbox").fadeToggle({ 
        speed:200,
        easing : "swing" 
      }) 
    $x(this).text($x(this).text() == 'Show Distributor Filters' ? 'Hide Distributor  Filters' : 'Show Distributor  Filters');
    return false;
            }); 
    });

    </script>
```

But when I have attempted to use adjust it like the code seen below, it just will not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
 $x("#clicky").click(function(){
    if($x("#slide").is(':visible'))
      {
  $x("#slide").animate({ width: 'hide' }); 
      }
      else
      {
        $x("#slide").animate({ width: 'show' }); 
      }
});
</script>
```

I hope that someone can see my flaw...thanks!!

Comment: hm. strange css behaivior - width: 'show'. You can use width -= div width to animate it, but show and hide are not options for this

Answer (score 0):

As Alternate You can also
Try this [JQUERY slideup & down widget](http://jqueryui.com/accordion)
Very Simple & Easy to understand..

Comment: I am able to accomplish the up & down action as seen by my first code sample...its just that I need to create a panel that sits at the left side of the screen...collapsed...and then onclick slide to the right allowing the user to make selections within the panel...